# Find the point where the perpendicular lines of two lines meet

Tags: javascript, math, geometry, 2d, line

I have two lines A and B whose co-ordinates are known.
I have to draw perpendiculars to each line, when the lines do not meet inside the green box.
Here, I am assuming that the green box is a canvas.

I need to find the points (x5,y5) where the perpendiculars of line A and line B meets.
Also, from which point should I draw perpendicular so that they meet the earliest.

[image][image: Image2]

Comment: What have youy tried in which language ?

Comment: Are you asking this for a particular language?  When you say you need to find (5, 5), is this the point equidistant along the line perpendicular to both line segment A and line segment B? Are these lines guaranteed to be parallel?  More details are needed.  You might also be better off in [Math.Stackexchange](http://math.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: @Bartdude: I have tried drawing perpendicular from mid point of each line. But, they do not intersect always. I am drawing this on canvas. So using javascript.

Comment: @nchen24: Yes, I am using javascript. The intersection points should be equidistant from lines. No, they are not parallel always. The criteria for taking perpendicular is that the lines do not intersect within the green box.

Comment: @Rohith "The intersection points should be equidistant from lines." you might want to add that to the question. Also, if your lines are parallel, you can do it pretty much wherever you want.

Comment: @Cimbali: I should have said "The intersection points could be equidistant from lines." Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: It sounds like you want to find the locus between the two lines.  To do that, you should bisect the angle they would intersect at, then find the minimum distance from points along that line to one of the line segments.

Comment: Pet Peeve: You do not appear to have lines in this image, you have line segments. Cheers!

Comment: Thanks all. I found what I need, It is called [Cobb Angle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cobb_angle)

Answer (score 1):

Your question does not have an unique solution. Assume line A and B are not parallel, then you can extend them in one direction so that they intersect and you shall find an angle defined by the intersecting point and two end points from line A and B. Find the bisecting line of this angle and every point on this bisecting line will satisfy your criteria. If line A and B are parallel, it will be easy to find another line parallel to line A and B and lie mid-way between them. Every point on this line will meet your criteria as well.

If by "meet earliest", you  mean the distance from (x5,y5) to lines A and B is minimized, then you can come up an unique solution when lines A and B are not parallel. The unique location for (x5, y5) can be decided in the following ways:

1) find the end point of line A and line B that is closer to the intersecting point. In your example, it will be point (x2,y2) and point (x4,y4)
2) project these two points along the direction perpendicular to the line itself and onto the bisecting line. In your example, project (x2, y2) along the yellow line direction onto the bisecting line. Do the same for point (x4,y4) but along the red line direction. 
3) You shall find two projection points from step (2) and whichever point is away from the intersection point of line A and B is the location for (x5, y5). 
4) From point (x5, y5), it should be easy for you to compute the perpendicular point on line A and B and compute the distance.

When lines A and B are parallel, the solution is still not unique even with the "minimum distance" criterion.

Comment: I understand "Also, from which point should I draw perpendicular so that they meet the earliest." as the distance between point 5 and lines A and B should be minimized.